# Styling `<body>` with Tailwind leading to `Prop `className` did not match` and a loss of certain styles

Tags: next.js13

I have styled my `<body>` tag in a layout.tsx file with the following TailwindCSS:
`h-full w-full grid grid-rows-1 auto-cols-auto`

Whenever the page loads, I get an error in the console:
`Prop 'className' did not match. Server: "h-full w-full" Client: "h-full w-full grid grid-rows-1 auto-cols-auto"`
None of the grid styles apply either.

I can remove the grid property and re-add it, and then hot reload seems to 'fix' it, and the grid styles start applying. However, if I reload again then it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This was just a rookie mistake due to me forgetting that the RootLayout applies to all routes. I was redefining `<body>` and `<html>` in my nested route.